Why am I getting this error "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'target' does not exist in type 'CameraConfig'"
I just got my code from another computer and this error shows up, I have been searching for some info but I dont know how to fix it, what Im trying to do here is to add a search bar in my google maps page
  async onSearch(event: any) {
    const query = event.target.value;

    if (query) {
      const geocodeUrl = ``;
      
      try {
        const response = await fetch(geocodeUrl);
        const data = await response.json();

        if (data.status === 'OK') {
          const location = data.results[0].geometry.location;
          this.map.setCamera({
            target: {
              lat: location.lat,
              lng: location.lng,
            },
            zoom: 15,
          });
        } else {
          console.error('No results found for the specified address.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching geocode:', error);
      }
    }
  }

}

I am using angular version 18.0.0 and ionic 8

Looking at the documentation Camera Config Type - Capacitor Docs. You should replace target with coordinate and the typescript error will go away.
    ...
    if (data.status === 'OK') {
      const location = data.results[0].geometry.location;
      this.map.setCamera({
        coordinate: { // <- changed here!
          lat: location.lat,
          lng: location.lng,
        },
        zoom: 15,
      });

